# Php: My framework disables direct file access, but I need to avoid this, how?

Tags: php, .htaccess, frameworks

.htaccess looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.ico)$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ entryPoint.php [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

this enforces all request running though entryPoint.php. This processes all files, redirects, etc. Images are free to go, there can be direct references to them. But what about CSS, JS files? I cant add exceptions - because it would reveal the directory structure. All I want is:
script src="ds.jss" while they can be at "js/" or "module/x/js/". Same with CSS.

I understand I can do it with entryPoint.php: file_get_contents and outputs. It does work, but its too slow. First we tried it with pictures too.

How to enable a "direct access"?

Comment: _"I cant add exceptions - because it would reveal the directory structure."_ What's the problem with that?

Answer (score 2):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ entryPoint.php [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Try adding these rewrite conditions...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do that within the php file, you need to add a rule:

Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^ds\.jss$ module/x/ds.jss [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|\.jpeg|\.bmp|\.ico)$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ entryPoint.php [QSA]
</IfModule>
```

The important part is the [`L` flag which stands for *Last* <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l). It will prevent the other rules to run.

If you want to resolve the filename dynamically but you don't want to use PHP to provide the actual file but your apache server, you can still use PHP to resolve the filename by creating a [dynamic rewrite map <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap), search for *External Rewriting Program*.

Comment: yea, its look good. But there are variable urls. For example in src "this.css" and the real URL can be "modules/SNOWTEMPLATE/this.css" or "modules/NORMALTEMPLATE/this.css"

Comment: You can not map the same request to different files at once. That will never work, regardless which technique you use. You need at least to define the criteria how to find the filename.

Comment: I added another note how you can resolve the URLs with PHP, but the file will be served as normal by apache (no readfile in PHP or such things).